# replace path in textfile with sed

Tags: linux, sed

I have a text file with the following line:

```
Directory="C:\Interface\LTS\BDU"
```

I need to replace this with:

```
Directory="C:\Interface\LTS\"
```

I have tried many combinations but it doesn’t seem to work.

Last one I tried is:

```
sudo sed -i 's|"\LTS\BDU"|"\LTS\"|' application.tmp
```

How do I manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo sed -i sed 's|\\LTS\\BDU|\\LTS\\|' application.tmp
```

1. You don't need the `"` in the sed command, because you aren't matching that character.
2. You need to escape the `\`s.